# keyboard input language changing program

Tags: vb.net

I have found some codes written in C# for changing input language programmatically. I adapted the codes for vb.net. But it is not working. Since i am new in programming i cannot find out my fault. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing

Namespace InputLanguagetrial
    Public Class Form1
        Dim _bengaliInput As InputLanguage
        Dim _englishInput As InputLanguage


        Public Sub New()
            _bengaliInput = GetInputLanguageByName("bengali")
            _englishInput = GetInputLanguageByName("english")
        End Sub

        Public Sub SetKeyboardLayout(ByVal layout As InputLanguage)
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = layout
        End Sub


        Public Shared Function GetInputLanguageByName(ByVal inputName As     String) As InputLanguage
            Dim lang As InputLanguage
            For Each lang In InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages
                If   lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToLower().StartsWith(inputName) Then
                    Return lang
                End If
            Next
            Return Nothing
        End Function

        Public Sub LoadBengaliKeyboardLayout()
            If Not _bengaliInput Is Nothing Then
                InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _bengaliInput
            Else
                InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =     InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub LoadEnglishKeyboardLayout()
            If Not _englishInput Is Nothing Then
              InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _englishInput
            Else
                InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _bengaliInput
        End Sub

        Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _englishInput
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Using the TextChanged event is very strange and too late to modify the keyboard layout.  Use the Enter event instead.

Comment: Of course, it has been change to GotFocus as suggested by GeniuS BraiN in his answer in the following coding. His (GeniuS BraiN's) coding is seemed to be perfect. But it is not working. Both textbox is presenting English. Kindly help.

Comment: `I have found some codes` <-- Where? Give a link. `But it is not working` <-- How exactly is it not working? Which behavior you expect? Which one you got instead? `i am new in programming` <-- copying code from other people is not how you learn programming, grab a book or (better) an online course that will help get you started.

Answer (score 2):

When converting some code between C# and VB.Net probably some changes will need to be done

- Remove the `New` sub and add its code to the '`Form_Load`' event.
- Changing the '`TextBox_TextChanged`' events to '`TextBox_GotFocus`' will give you a better result (the language will change once the cursor is moved to the TextBox).

**Here:**

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim _bengaliInput As InputLanguage
    Dim _englishInput As InputLanguage

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _bengaliInput = GetInputLanguageByName("bengali")
        _englishInput = GetInputLanguageByName("english")
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetKeyboardLayout(ByVal layout As InputLanguage)
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = layout
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetInputLanguageByName(ByVal inputName As String) As InputLanguage
        Dim lang As InputLanguage
        For Each lang In InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages
            If lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToLower().StartsWith(inputName) Then
                Return lang
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub LoadBengaliKeyboardLayout()
        If Not _bengaliInput Is Nothing Then
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _bengaliInput
        Else
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadEnglishKeyboardLayout()
        If Not _englishInput Is Nothing Then
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _englishInput
        Else
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _bengaliInput
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.GotFocus
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = _englishInput
    End Sub

End Class
```

Hope that helps :)

**Edit:**

Of course you need to add the Bengali keyboard in your Windows settings in order for this code to work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response. But the code still not working. In both textbox it is showing English while typing. This time, of course, I omit the "Namespace InputLanguagetrial" line and its ending part. Is it necessary? If i put it it shows error.

Comment: @user3527068
- If it's showing English in both TextBoxes, then you probably didn't enable the Bengali as an input language in your system (please check the 'Edit' section in my answer above).
- In VB.Net you don't need to add the Namespace as in C#.. if you do, then you'll have to add it in the designer file as well (just forget about it).

Comment: OK. Thanks again. But I want to perform this task without going to Windows setting, I mean programmatically. Is it not possible? I have seen some applications which change the keyboard input language without going into any Windows setting (which we can call typing software).

Comment: Great! Perfect! It is working fine in your ways. But I want to do this without touching the Windows settings menually.

Comment: In order to use any input language, it has to be installed in your system

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed ,, Excellent coding... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tow input language in your Operating System (windows), you must have one as default language. For example if you have English input language as the default & Arabic input language as the second input language.

you can switch between the tow input language by using F1 , F2 keys by this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then  
         ' for English language
         InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =nputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(0)
    elseif e.KeyCode= Keys.F2 Then
         ' for Arabic language
         InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =nputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(1)
    End If
End Sub
```